# Audio capture to a file using DirectShow from a mic (Any alternative to 'AudioRecorder WAV Dest' )

Tags: visual-c++, audio, directshow

reference: http  www codeproject com/KB/audio-video/cacsave.aspx?msg=3094764#xx3094764xx

I can't find anything like 'AudioRecorder WAV Dest'. Is there any alternative for this as in my PC graphEdit shows these: (Part 1 n related has worked nicely.)

```
WM Speech Encoder DMO,
WMAudio Encoder DMO,
IAC2,
IMA ADPCM,
PCM,
Microsoft ADPCM,
ACELP.net,
DSP Group TrueSpeech(TM),
Windows Media Audio V1,
Windows Media Audio V2,
GSM 6.10,
Microsoft G.723.1,
CCITT A-Law,
CCITT u-Law,
MPEG Layer-3,
Realtek HD Audio output,
Default DirectSound Device,
Default WaveOut Device,
DirectSound: Realtek HD Audio output,
WMAudio Decoder DMO,
WMSpeech Decoder DMO,
Mpeg4s Decoder DMO,
WMV Screen decoder DMO,
WMVideo Decoder DMO,
Mpeg43 Decoder DMO,
Mpeg4 Decoder DMO,
WMT MuxDeMux Filter,
Full Screen Renderer,
DV Muxer,
Color Space Converter,
WM ASF Reader,
AVI Splitter,
WMT AudioAnalyzer,
VGA 16 Color Ditherer,
Indeo® video 5.10 Compression Filter,
Windows Media Audio Decoder,
VideoSync Extended Filter for OpenCV,
AC3 Parser Filter,
WMT Format Conversion,
StreamBufferSink,
CalibFilter,
WMT Black Frame Generator,
MJPEG Decompressor,
Indeo® video 5.10 Decompression Filter,
WMT Screen Capture filter,
Microsoft Screen Video Decompressor,
MPEG-I Stream Splitter,
SAMI (CC) Parser,
MPEG Layer-3 Decoder,
MPEG-2 Splitter,
ACELP.net Sipro Lab Audio Decoder,
Internal Script Command Renderer,
MPEG Audio Decoder,
File Source (Netshow URL),
WMT Import Filter,
DV Splitter,
Bitmap Generate,
Windows Media Video Decoder,
Video Mixing Renderer 9,
Windows Media Video Decoder,
WMT VIH2 Fix,
Record Queue,
Windows Media Multiplexer,
ASX file Parser,
ASX v.2 file Parser,
NSC file Parser,
ACM Wrapper,
Windows Media source filter,
Video Renderer,
Frame Eater,
MPEG-2 Video Stream Analyzer,
Line 21 Decoder,
Video Port Manager,
WST Decoder,
Video Renderer,
WM ASF Writer,
WMT Sample Information Filter,
VBI Surface Allocator,
Microsoft MPEG-4 Video Decompressor,
File writer,
WMT Log Filter,
WMT Virtual Renderer,
DVD Navigator,
Overlay Mixer2,
AVI Draw,
.RAM file Parser,
WMT DirectX Transform Wrapper,
G.711 Codec,
MPEG-2 Demultiplexer,
DV Video Decoder,
Indeo® audio software,
Windows Media Update Filter,
ASF DIB Handler,
ASF ACM Handler,
ASF ICM Handler,
ASF URL Handler,
ASF JPEG Handler,
ASF DJPEG Handler,
ASF embedded stuff Handler,
9x8Resize,
WIA Stream Snapshot Filter,
ProxyTrans,
Allocator Fix,
SampleGrabber,
Null Renderer,
WMT Virtual Source,
WMT Interlacer,
StreamBufferSource,
Smart Tee,
Overlay Mixer,
AVI Decompressor,
Uncompressed Domain Shot Detection FilterAVI/WAV File Source,
QuickTime Movie Parser,
Wave Parser,
MIDI Parser,
Multi-file Parser,
File stream renderer,
XML Playlist,
AVI Mux,
Line 21 Decoder 2,
File Source (Async.),
File Source (URL),
WMT DV Extract,
WMT Switch Filter,
WMT Volume,
Stretch Video,
Infinite Pin Tee Filter,
QT Decompressor,
MPEG Video Decoder,
Indeo® video 4.4 Decompression Filter,
Indeo® video 4.4 Compression Filter,
Default MidiOut Device,
Microsoft GS Wavetable SW Synth,
MSScreen encoder DMO,
WMVideo9 Encoder DMO,
MSScreen 9 encoder DMO,
DV Video Encoder,
Indeo® video 5.10 Compression Filter,
MJPEG Compressor,
Cinepak Codec by Radius,
Intel 4:2:0 Video V2.50,
Intel Indeo(R) Video R3.2,
Intel Indeo® Video 4.5,
Indeo® video 5.10,
Intel IYUV codec,
Microsoft H.261 Video Codec,
Microsoft H.263 Video Codec,
Microsoft RLE,
Microsoft Video 1,

Realtek HD Digital input,
Realtek HD Audio Input.
```

And which one is the common Name exists in almost all windows PC to save a wave file. For now for WinXPSP2+.

-Rahul

Answer (score 2):

Wav dest is an example that you can compile from the DirectShow examples that come with the SDK.  You can compile it up and register it.

It does suffer from limitations surrounding the 2gig wave file limit (This was a big problem for me using 64-channel audio).  I have found that using the AVI Mux filter (CLSID_AviDest) is a great way of getting round the limitations of the wave file format.

Comment: BTW AVIs have file size limit as well

Comment: @RomanR. Sort of.  Quite a long time ago AVIs introduced a method for allowing more than one AVI data block in the RIFF format.  That said the RIFF header size would then be wrong ... but you could still navigate by jumping through the blocks normally.

Comment: MSDN says ["Increased AVI file size (greater than 1 GB)"](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/dd318188) and indeed AVI Mux can create AVIs larger than 1 GB. The problem is that it hits another problem reaching 2 (or 4 GB, not sure) and larger files are not playable ([supposedly related link](http://www.avi-io.com/2_4_gig_issue.htm)). If there is a need in large files with raw audio, I would look into MP4 and MKV containers,

Comment: @RomanR. Really? I know FAT32 limits files to 4GB but I thought the extension above (AVI2 it would seem) basically only limits you by the file system's max size.  NTFS is something like 16 Exabytes.

Comment: The link mentions several issues, and those file system related are pretty clear (might be ignored for now). I am under impression that it is 2 GB limit passing which there is either error writing further, or no error but the file is broken.

Comment: @RomanR. I must be missing where it says that in your links because I don't see that at all.  I do agree that some software won't handle these AVI2 files but thats more a problem with that software than the AVI2 format ...

Comment: A better link on 2GB problem: [Video For Windows 2GB limitation](https://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/windowsdesktop/en-US/ce4d8ed5-ecd9-46c1-aff2-fc81b3342a6e/video-for-windows-2gb-limitation?forum=windowsdirectshowdevelopment) Note "After ending up with a corrupt AVI file following an seemingly successful AVI file write..." then "... If you want to use this format you will need to either **write your own mux**... " - it matches my memories that 2+ GB files are produced broken.

Comment: "New-fangled DirectShow stuff"!?   Come on ... it clearly explains that AVI2 resolves the 2GB problem :P